# Navbar de bootstrap, no sé separar la imagen del texto

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, django, navbar

para Django, de la pagina de bootstrap cogi el ejemplo de navbar y no consigo que los elementos imagen y texto se separen, desconozco cual es la propiedad que lo hace.
La clase intro-img e intro-text, se superponen, y quisiera que, aunque estuvieran superpuesta poder mover intro-text hacia la derecha.

```
{% extends "miwebapp/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<!-- Heading -->
<section class="page-section clearfix">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="intro">
        <img class="intro-img img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0 rounded" src="{% static '/miwebapp/img/puntualidad.jpg' %}" alt="">
        <div class="intro-text left-0 text-center bg-faded p-5 rounded">
            <h2 class="section-heading mb-4" >
                <span class="section-heading-lower">-.fidelium.-</span>
                <span class="section-heading-upper">Deus, qui corda fidelium Sancti Spíritus</span>
            </h2>
            <p class="mb-3">illustratione docuisti, da nobis in eodum Spíritu recta sápere, et de ejus semper consolatione gaudere. Amen.</p>
            <a href="{% url 'Presentacion' %}">Leer más...</a>                
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>        
<!-- Message -->
<section class="page-section cta">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
                <div class="cta-inner text-center rounded">
                    <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
                        <span class="section-heading-lower">-. Sub tuum .-</span>
                        <span class="section-heading-upper">Sub tuum praesidium confugimus, Sancta Dei Genetrix.</span>
                    </h2>
                    <p class="mb-0">Nostras deprecationes ne despicias in necessitatibus, sed a periculis cunctis libera nos semper, Virgo gloriosa et benedicta. Amen.</p>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{% static '/miwebapp/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel = "stylesheet">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:400,400i,700,700i" rel = "stylesheet">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{% static '/miwebapp/css/gestion.css'%}" rel = "stylesheet">
    <title>Mi Web</title>
</head>
```

gestion.css

```
.intro {
  position:relative;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .intro .intro-img {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  .intro .intro-text {
    left: 600;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    background-color: rgba(21, 49, 126);
    color: rgb(255, 220, 220);
    position: absolute;
  }
  .intro .intro-text .intro-button {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2rem;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .intro .intro-text {
    width: 45%;
  }
}
```

¿Podeís ayudarme?
Estaria bien que alguien hiciera un videotutorial explicando linea a linea bootstrap, sin que empezaran como instalar Windows (sarcasmo). Si en concreto hay alguna pagina que lo explique, lo de bootstrap, no lo de windows, estaria interesado.
Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 0):

### Errores

1. Las clases `intro-img` y `intro-text` no son de bootstrap.
2. La clase left-0 elimina el margin
3. La clase left-0 tiene más importancia. El orden de las clases también hace que el CSS sea más o menos importante, por lo que la última clase tendrá el CSS con mayor prioridad (Si el selector es del mismo nivel. [W3school lo explica mejor](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp))

Con una búsqueda en google puedes acceder a la [documentación de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

En cuanto al videotutorial... Prefiero ahorrarme comentarios en la respuesta

Comment: pues algunas clases que mencionas no están en bootstrap, por otro lado estaría bien que menciones que versión tienes, no es lo mismo la versión 3 y la 5, dicho eso las clases que puedes usar para generar los espacios pueden ser "p-1, p-2...p-6" y "m-1, m-2 .... m-6"

Comment: la version que utilizo es la v5.2.0, segun bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 0):

con el float:right; se me soluciono.

```
  .intro .intro-text {
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    float: right;
    background-color: rgba(21, 49, 126);
    color: rgb(255, 220, 220);
    /*position: absolute;*/
  }
```